# Parsing a arbitrary textual data format

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

I am trying to parse a `.rtf` file that was created by someone else, and I don't have control over the file contents or format.  There are several blocks to the file and each block has a set of information that I need to get.  Each block is set up like this:

```
[Title]
[Type] ([sub type])
Level: [CSV list of levels]
Components: [CSV list of components]
Time: [proprietary time format]
Length: [length value]
Target: [target text]
Dwell: [dwell time in proprietary time format]
Saves: [yes/no]
Additional Information: [additional information]
[notes]
```

There may be from 50 to 100 blocks like the one above in each file.  I have used the `NSRegularExpression` class to do some other parsing in my app, but I can't even think about how to accomplish this.

As far as I can tell, each block is separated by a double line.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing for this, really.  The only regular expressions I have ever gotten to work, in my past, are for simple, single line items.

Comment: You probably need NSScanner....

Comment: If I could just have someone give me a starting point, that would probably help out a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a `NSScanner`, like this:

```
NSString *input = 
    @"[Title]\n"
    @"[Type] ([sub type])\n"
    @"Level: [CSV list of levels]\n"
    @"Components: [CSV list of components]\n"
    @"Time: [proprietary time format]\n"
    @"Length: [length value]\n"
    @"Target: [target text]\n"
    @"Dwell: [dwell time in proprietary time format]\n"
    @"Saves: [yes/no]\n"
    @"Additional Information: [additional information]\n"
    @"[notes]\n";

NSString *title, *type, *subType, *level, *components, *time, *length, *target, *dwell, *saves, *additional, *notes;
title = type = subType = level = components = time = length = target = dwell = saves = additional = notes = nil;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];

// read the first line into title...
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&title];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:nil];

// read the first part of the second line into type
[scanner scanUpToString:@" (" intoString:&type];
[scanner scanString:@"(" intoString:nil];

// read the next part of the second line into subType
[scanner scanUpToString:@")" intoString:&subType];

// read the end of the line
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:nil];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:nil];

// read in level
[scanner scanString:@"Level: " intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&level];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:nil];

// read in components:
[scanner scanString:@"Components: " intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&components];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:nil];

// read in time:
[scanner scanString:@"Time: " intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&time];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:nil];

// read in length
[scanner scanString:@"Length: " intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&length];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:nil];

// complete for all other metadata

NSLog(@"%@", title);
NSLog(@"%@ (%@)", type, subType);
NSLog(@"%@", level);
NSLog(@"%@", components);
NSLog(@"%@", time);
NSLog(@"%@", length);
NSLog(@"%@", target);
NSLog(@"%@", dwell);
NSLog(@"%@", saves);
NSLog(@"%@", additional);
NSLog(@"%@", notes);
```

This works for me, obviously complete the process for all the other fields.

Comment: Well, I figured out that I can just convert the .rtf files to normal text files, which I can then break up the contents of by using `[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];` method.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I can just convert the .rtf files to regular text files.  This allows me to process them more easily.

Thanks for the help!  I am going to look into using the NSScanner to do this more elegantly.